# Generating separate files for partial classes in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, t4, auto-generate, typewriter

I'm working on a project that uses MSLinqToSQLGenerator to generate partial classes that reflect the database. It generates a single file (Database.designer.cs) with a number of partial classes that reflect tables and stored procedures and whatnot.

The `Database.designer.cs` file is essentially this:

```cs
namespace Name.Space
{
    public partial class SomeClass1
    {
        // stuff
    }

    public partial class SomeClass2
    {
        // stuff
    }

    public partial class SomeClass3
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Now, another part of the project uses Typewriter extension for Visual Studio to autogenerate Typescript files from classes. Now, Typewriter works on a one file to one file principle, meaning I can't separate multiple classes in one .cs file into separate .ts files (which is what I need, essentially).

So I thought of using the T4 templating to do the following:

1. Read the content of `Database.designer.cs` file
2. Get the list of all partial classes
3. Generate a new file for each class (`<class-name>.cs`) that contains only the following code

```cs
namespace Name.Space
{
    public partial class SomeClass1
    {
        //
    }
}
```

That way, the Typewriter will be able to read individual .cs files and generate appropriate .ts files.

**What I need is specific T4 code to read the `Database.designer.cs` file and output each class to its own file.**

(I've tried tutorials, I've tried code examples and all I got was a headache and sudden desire to change my career path...)

Comment: It's 2017 why are you still using linq-to-sql? EF code first dose this already.

Comment: It's a collaborative project, it wasn't my call... I've already asked to move away from that on to something modern.

Comment: They seam to support [paratial](https://github.com/frhagn/Typewriter/issues/127) as of  28 dec 2016.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I overcomplicated it. It was a matter of opening the target .cs file as a File object, reading it by lines and simply extracting the necessary class names. This is a combination of several posts I found online (various sources I don't remember), and a component from Tangible T4 `TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude`.

```cs
<#@ template  debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#
    string absolutePath = Host.ResolvePath("..\\Database.designer.cs");
    string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(absolutePath);

    List<string> selectedContent = new List<string>();
    string[] separators = new string[] { " " };

    foreach (var csFileRow in contents)
    {
        if (csFileRow.Contains("public partial class"))
        {
            var tmpSplit = csFileRow.Split(' ');
            var tmpString = tmpSplit[3]; // public partial class <targetClassName> (4th member)

            if (tmpString.Contains("Result")) // Example: SearchRolesResult
            {
                selectedContent.Add(tmpString);
            }
        }
    }

    var manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this);
#>
<#
    foreach (var classItem in selectedContent)
    {
        manager.StartNewFile(classItem + ".cs");
#>
namespace Name.Space
{
    public partial class <#= classItem #>
    {
    }
}

<#
        manager.EndBlock();
    }
    manager.Process();

#>
```

Then, as Filip Cordas mentioned above, in the .tst file generator, I specified the following:

```js
Template(Settings settings)
{
    settings.PartialRenderingMode = PartialRenderingMode.Combined;
}
```

which resulted in .ts files that had complete the class with all properties I needed.